# why running outside of angular zone still triggering change

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-allen-0eiv5?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

isn't running this code outside the zone supposed to not trigger changes in the title property ?

when exactly the runOutsideAngular applies?

Comment: the `change()` method is triggered by Angular, and is outside the `runOutsideAngular` method - hence change detection is still triggered

Comment: but the code that changes the title is inside the runOutsideAngular block..

Comment: you have to remember that everything runs within the context of a scheduler, and so operations are queued and executed in one tick of the event loop.  At some point, change detection runs once per event loop.

Comment: ok, but still I dont understand why if I isolate the title change code in this runOutsideAngular block it still changes...